# What kind of cryptographic mechanism uses repeated xor's?

Tags: security, cryptography, encryption

I'm attempting to analyze a short encryption program and figure out which mechanism it's using.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[] ) {
    long int key;
    char * endptr;

    key = strtol( argv[1], &endptr, 10 );

    srandom( key );
    { /* now copy input to output through crypt transformation */
            char ch;
            while (!feof( stdin )) {
                    putc( (getc(stdin) ^ random())&0xFF, stdout );
            }
            fclose( stdout );
    }
}
```

I can follow this simply, but I'm having trouble trying to weed out which mechanism it's using..

I'm looking at the following:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stream_cipher

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie-Hellman

I'm leaning towards iterated block cyphers but I really have no idea at this point.

Comment: None of the above. You wouldn't be able to implement any of those in one line of code. Think simpler.

Comment: @EJP Actually, it's a very simple stream cipher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to clearly distinguish in your mind the ciphers in categories. There are:

- Block ciphers, which operate in fixed-size blocks of input
- Stream ciphers, which operate on data streams (i.e. one byte at a time)

*The above only distinguishes ciphers by the size of the input they accept; it has nothing to do with the mechanism they use to produce the encrypted text.*

Regarding this mechanism, we have:

- Substitution ciphers
- Transposition ciphers
- And many other types which are basically combinations of the above, possibly with many iterations

So try to answer this question first:

**Is your example a stream cipher or a block cipher? Remember, this has nothing to do with *how* it encrypts!**

Comment: Thanks for laying it out like that. How would I then go about determining the size of the encryption key in bits? I have to look within srandom man?

Comment: @JohnRedyns: What is the variable input that causes this program to encrypt to a different ciphertext each time? What variable/structure do you use to store it? How many bits does that storage have?

Comment: Wouldn't it just be the length of the inputted string?

Comment: @JohnRedyns: No, because the values you XOR the input string with can be produced from something much shorter. If someone gives me the "random" key "ABC" and I encrypt with "AABBCC", I didn't magically make the key longer. Someone who knows how I derived it can decrypt if they are told "ABC", so *that* is the key. In this case, they key is... `key`, because it can be used to derive everything else in a repeatable (deterministic) manner.

Answer (score 3):

It's a stream cipher. The cipherkey is generated by seeding srandom with the given key.

> In cryptography, a stream cipher is a
>   symmetric key cipher where plaintext
>   bits are combined with a pseudorandom
>   cipher bit stream (keystream),
>   typically by an exclusive-or (xor)
>   operation. In a stream cipher the
>   plaintext digits are encrypted one at
>   a time, and the transformation of
>   successive digits varies during the
>   encryption.

Which is what you're doing here. `key` is the symmetric key, and the cipher stream is generated by random(). The call to srandom(key) assures that the random stream will ke the same as long as your key is the same.

Comment: No other mechanisms use srandom?

Comment: See my update. Other mechanisms could use srandom; for example to come up with a 64bit key from a smaller key. But in this case the purpose of srandom and random follow the definition of a stream cipher.

Comment: It should go without saying, of course, that this is an extremely weak cipher - random/srandom are not cryptographically secure PRNGs.